# Prove that the sequence of functions $x^nLogx$ is uniformly convergent on [0,1]

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

[Here is an image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CimW.png)

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ defined on [0,1] by:

$f_n(x) = x^nLogx$ if $x≠ 0$ & $f_n(0)=0$

Prove that the sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly on [0,1].

I first showed that it is pointwise convergent and then I tried to show that it's uniformly convergent by taking the derivative of a function that bounds the given sequence (in hope of finding a maximum that depends only on n) but I can't seem to move further because the function that is bounding the sequence is strictly increasing between 0 and 1.
[Here is my work in details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P16po.jpg)

Also, in the next part. I'm trying to show that $g_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent on [0,1]. I followed the same steps and couldn't get anywhere. I think if I can solve the first part then I can solve this one.
[Here is my work in details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWn0.jpg)

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ with $f_n'(x) = (n\log{x}+1)x^{n-1}$ for $x\in (0,1)$. Hence $f_n$ has a unique stationary point at $x = e^{-1/n}$ and since $f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$ we conclude $|f_n(x)| \le |f_n(e^{-1/n})| = \frac{e^{-1}}{n}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Since $ \frac{e^{-1}}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ we conclude $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Applying the above to $g_n = nf_n$ we see $g_n(e^{-1/n}) = e^{-1}$ so $g_n$ cannot converge uniformly to $0$ (and since it converges pointwise to $0$ it cannot converge uniformly to anything else either).

Comment: I tried this method but here is why I changed it:


$f_n'(x)=(nLogx+1)x^{n-1} = 0$ --> $x=e^{-1/n}$

Now I have to study the sign of $f_n'(x)$. When is $f_n'(x)$ positive? It's when $(nLogx+1)x^{n-1}>0$ and since $x^{n-1}$ is always positive for our interval then $f_n'(x)$ is positive when $(nLogx+1)>0$ which means that $x>e^{-1/n}$ and by the same logic $f_n'(x)$ is negative when $x<e^{-1/n}$. This means that $f_n(x)$ is bounded from below with $f_n(e^{-1/n})$ and not from above. Can you please tell me where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: @CombatWombat There is no flaw in this logic - $f_n$ is non-positive in $[0,1]$ so the stationary point is indeed a minimum. However this doesn't matter since we only need to bound $|f_n|$ above, not $f_n$ (for which this works).

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot.